# Use excel to summarise data from a column by identifier

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a column called MRN (the identifier) and the drugs administered next to them. There are duplicates of the MRN in column A that correspond to different courses of drugs. What I'm hoping to do is to summarise all the drugs administered associated with one MRN in one line, removing all duplicates. It looks something like this.

```
|   | A   |   B   |
| 1 | MRN   Item
| 2 | 1   cefoTAXime
| 3 | 1   ampicillin
| 4 | 1   cefoTAXime
| 5 | 1   vancomycin
| 6 | 1  cefTRIaxone
| 7 | 2   ampicillin
| 8 | 2   vancomycin
| 9 | 2   vancomycin
```

I have 3 different formulas. The first is to produce a list of MRNs that are all unique. The second is to pull all drugs by MRN and list them in one line. The third is to remove duplicates from this list. They are below (in order).

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$2885, MATCH(0,COUNTIF(D$1:$D1, $A$2:$A$2885),0 )),"")}

{=INDEX($A$2:$B$2885,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$2885=$D2,ROW($A$2:$A$2885)),COLUMN(D:D))-4,2)}

{=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$AE$2, MATCH(0,COUNTIF(D$3:$D3, $E$2:$AE$2),0 )),"")}
```

*I know that I can edit the second one by adding IF(ISERROR ...) to remove NA and print blanks if drug not found, but want to keep the formulas as simple as possible at this time.

My problem is that second formula isn't pulling all the drugs by MRN, and in an ideal world I would be able to combine the second and third formula into one, but I am not sure how to. Here is a link to a test file that shows my issue and the formulas in action.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApoCMYBhswHzhooXnumW2iV7yx-JaA

I appreciate that there may be a better way to do this using python/R, and if that's possible then I'm more than happy to try, but I couldn't make any headway. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you could deal with a count of the number of courses per drug per MRN, you can do this with `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform` in Excel 2016)

Starting with the data you provided on your worksheet, the results would look like:

[image]

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"MRN", Int64.Type}, {"Item", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"MRN"}, {{"Count", each _, type table}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"MRN", "Item"}, {"Count.MRN", "Count.Item"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Count", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Count"[Count.Item]), "Count.Item", "Count.MRN", List.NonNullCount)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```